# what is happening to the stack when using process.nextTick

Tags: node.js, stack-overflow

I'm computing some heavy recursive function (let's say Fibonacci for the following code)
I have two versions : 
- first one, vanilla recursive (uncommenting "if(false)" )
- the second one, using the process.nextTick every 5 calls in order to let other code run (uncommenting "if(n%5==0)" )

now running first one gets me a "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
while running the second one provides me with a nice "196418"

here's the code. Could you tell me what's going on, because I can't believe that process.nextTick is cleaning the stack.

```
'use strict';

function fibo_cb( n, cb ){ fibo_rec( n, (res) => cb( res ) ); }

function fibo_rec( n, ret ){
    if( n<2 ){
        ret( 1 );
    } else {
        let rr = (res_1) => { return (res_2) => ret(res_1+res_2) };
        let r = (res_1) => fibo_rec( n-2, rr(res_1) );
        //if(false){ //no tick
        if(n%5==0){ //do tick, once every 5
            process.nextTick( () => fibo_rec( n-1, r ) );
        } else {
            fibo_rec( n-1, r );
        }
    }
}

fibo_cb( 26, console.log );
```

Comment: *I can't believe that process.nextTick is cleaning the stack.* It sure is

Comment: @CertainPerformance please, do explain what can be cleaned in this case, I don't get what function calls may be discarded before completion of the last call to "ret(1)"

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript code is executed by putting all the code in Call Stack by creating scopes at function level. Since JavaScript is single threaded(apart from Asynchronous tasks), starting from Global level each scope is put into the call stack one by one until it reaches all the functions. Once the function gets completed it is popped out of the Call Stack.

In case of Recursive Functions, for each recursive call a function is pushed to Call Stack. **So when there are large number of recursive calls the Call Stack gets full since a maximum limit is fixed for Call Stack**.

Any Asynchronous Task scheduled using `process.nextTick` waits till call stack is empty and takes each callback from the *Event Queue* and pushes it to *Call Stack*. This happens repeatedly till all the recursive callbacks are finished.

Since Call Stack is emptied each time the is no *"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"* observed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I get that recursive function calls stack until the functions return. And also imagine that each call to nextTick may get to collect any garbage left from mallocs corresponding to its work, or also can wait for the stack to be "empty" (or maybe less full..) But is there not a dependency here in the calls from fibonacci ? How can these stacking calls (which cause the first version to overflow) be best managed in the second case if the dependency does not allow to get them out of the stack before the deepest call returns ?

Comment: Recursive Functions by nature create dependency between each function call. So in case of nextTick(), instead of Call Stack getting filled with functions Event queue is filled with callbacks.